# My SQL Syntax error for multiple commands in one query, working for each command running separately

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I'm trying to run the following MySQL command:

```
USE database_name;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS only_with_balance;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS keys_to_match;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE only_with_balance as (
    SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    transactions t 
WHERE 
    t.balance is not NULL
    and (t.transaction_status_id = 4 or t.transaction_status_id = 5)
    and (t.date between "2022-05-01" and "2022-08-24" )
```

);

But I'm getting a syntax error while trying to run the all the commands at once.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS only_with_balance;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXIST' at line 2
```

When I run each command separately, the result is the expected.

Can someone help me here?
What am I forgetting?

Comment: `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXIST` ... this seems to imply that you are not running what you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, by default the query interface only allows one SQL statement per call.

There's an option to enable multi-query per call, but it must be set at connect time. Some MySQL connectors do this by default, or allow it as an option, but some do not. You didn't say if you're writing code or if you're submitting this set of queries through a client (though you tag the question 'dbeaver' you don't say anything else about that). So I can't guess what interface you're using for these queries.

Anyway, there's no advantage to using multi-query. The default mode is one SQL statement per call. That's what I do.

Using the default mode of a single SQL statement per call has some advantages:

- Supports prepared statements and bound parameters (you can't run multiple statements in a single prepare call, even if you enable multi-query).
- Simplifies processing errors and warnings.
- Simplifies processing result sets.

Comment: This answer would be practical and more helpful if the way to enable multi-query was given, at least a reference to it in the MySQL docs or something.

Comment: @E-Riz, Each connector has a different way of enabling multi-query, but the OP didn't identify which connector they are using, so I couldn't link to any documentation. If you read some of my other answers, I often do link to supporting documentation and examples. Also, as I wrote above, there is hardly ever a good reason to use multi-query, and several reasons to avoid it.